# Formatting objects with unicode string and without unicode method

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

Quite often I find my self logging objects like:

```
result = call_a_func(XXX)
logger.info(u"I caught an exception {}".format(result))
```

The issue is that if result is an object with a string with unicode characters (still a bytestring) and doesn't have a `__unicode__` method this will blow up.

example:

```
try:
    # Exception with a unicode encoded in a string with utf-8
    raise Exception("\xea\xb5\xad")  # Note this is not usually created under my control
except Exception as e:
    return u"I captured: {}".format(e)
```

What is the best way to log objects coming from an external library where you are not sure you will be able to transform it to unicode?

Is there anything better than passing it through a function like:

```
def as_unicode(in_obj):
    try:
        return unicode(in_obj)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return str(in_obj).decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Not really. If code isn't `unicode`-ready then there's nothing that can be done about it.